# Save React form values to firebase real time database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have done this code it shows console output properly on writing console.log() method but it doesn't store code to my database.

It doesn't shows any other errors but don't store data to database, so please tell me what to change to make to store to database.

Here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    var firebase = require('firebase');
    var uuid = require('uuid');

    var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyDf5i7ULK0JTWYM3_X3wMQPUaaLPRYExC0",
        authDomain: "usurvey-419eb.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://usurvey-419eb.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "usurvey-419eb",
        storageBucket: "usurvey-419eb.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "395101866940"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    class Usurvey extends Component {
      constructor(props)
      {
        super(props);
        this.state={
          uid:uuid.v1(),
          firstName: '',
          lastName:''
        };
        this.submitData=this.submitData.bind(this);
        this.inputData=this.inputData.bind(this);
      }
      submitData()
      {
        document.write({uid: this.state.uid,firstName:this.state.firstName,lastName:this.state.lastName});
        // document.write(this.state.firstName);
        // document.write(this.state.lastName);


        firebase.database().ref('Newdata/'+this.state.uid).set({
          firstName: this.state.firstName,
          lastName: this.state.lastName
        });
      }
      inputData(event)
      {
        var firstName = this.refs.name1.value;
        var lastName = this.refs.name1.value;
        console.log(this.state.uid,this.state.firstName,this.state.lastName);

        this.setState({firstName:firstName, lastName:lastName});
        console.log(this.state.firstName,this.state.lastName);
      }
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
              <input type="text" onChange={this.inputData} ref="name1"/>
              <input type="text" onChange={this.inputData} ref="name2"/>
            <input type="submit" />Submit
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Usurvey;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a form you have to prevent the default behavior otherwise your page will refresh. Pass the submit event as an argument to your submitData()function and prevent the default behavior like so...

```
submitData(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref(`Newdata/${this.state.uid}`)
          .set({
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
          })

      }
```

Forms are old school HTML, from the days before single page applications, so when using them in a fancy new framework like react you have to specifically tell it not to automatically reload the page. It reloads by default because that is how the web used to work until single page applications came along.

Provided all code and added a console log from the database onMount to show that the data is being stored and retrieved. Copy into editor and it should work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const firebase = require('firebase');
const uuid = require('uuid');

const config = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyDf5i7ULK0JTWYM3_X3wMQPUaaLPRYExC0',
  authDomain: 'usurvey-419eb.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://usurvey-419eb.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'usurvey-419eb',
  storageBucket: 'usurvey-419eb.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '395101866940',
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

class Usurvey extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      uid: uuid.v1(),
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
    };
    this.submitData = this.submitData.bind(this);
    this.inputData = this.inputData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`Newdata/${this.state.uid}`)
      .on('value', snap => console.log('from db', snap.val()));
  }

  submitData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`Newdata/${this.state.uid}`)
      .set({
        firstName: this.state.firstName,
        lastName: this.state.lastName,
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  inputData(event) {
    const firstName = this.refs.name1.value;
    const lastName = this.refs.name2.value;
    this.setState({ firstName, lastName });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.inputData} ref="name1" />
          <input type="text" onChange={this.inputData} ref="name2" />
          <input type="submit" />Submit
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Usurvey;
```

Comment: also changed const lastName = this.refs.name2.value;, you had is set to 1 which was duplication

Comment: I ran the code in an editor and it works fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: Do I required to add componentDidMount() method??

Comment: not, that was just to prove that it working. Since I can't see your firebase console, I had to log the data to show it got saved.

Comment: No errors but when I filled my data and then hit enter page doesn't get reload and I have to manually reload it by cmd+r button only....

Comment: There is no reason to reload anything. The data gets saved when you hit submit. What do else do you want it to do on submit?

Comment: suppose I filled a form and then I want to reload that page to blank those fields, so other details can be filled out. Something like that!

Comment: Well, if you want to empty the field you add something like `this.refs.name2.value = ''` after the firebase call in the submit function. This is a separate question though. You should open a new question for this so that other people searching for the same problem don't get confused.

Comment: If my response answered your question please accept the answer. If not let me know what the problem is. Also, if you're building complex forms you might want to use controlled components instead of refs. The react docs is a good place to start https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: Yes, for sure!! Thanks a lot for everything. 

I need a help that can you just tell me where is the best documentation and learning material for reactjs?

Comment: React docs for sure, I posted a link in my previous comment. Frontend master has a great paid course for [Firebase and React](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/firebase-react/). If you looking for form specific help in react and you are willing to pay then I strongly recommend [The Missing Forms Handbook](https://goshakkk.name/the-missing-forms-handbook-of-react/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164885/discussion-between-yash-choksi-and-josh-pittman).

Comment: Can I write that function without preventDefault method and also saves data to database?
Because if I submitted all details and I press enter page must have to reload so it can able to accept new data!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you don't want to submit then you can just store the data in state till you are ready to submit. Alternatively, if you just want to clear the inputs after submit you can set the input ref value to null at the end of your submit function. If you open a new question and explain what you are trying to do then more of us can help.

Comment: Actually I created a new question and get some progress but still not achieved, I will post question link so you can help me....

Comment: Preventdefault method confusion please search this question and look at there....

Comment: Please post the link